# "Title cannot be longer than 150 characters" - why doesn't the field have an input limit or a character count then?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, title

This is really frustrating. Having to edit a title because it was "too long" despite the title field not having a hard limit or a character count.

Comment: Are you trying to edit an older post that has a title longer than 150 characters?

Comment: I suppose that you could add the `feature-request` tag to this question, if that's what you mean.

Comment: This was closed as a duplicate. I updated the status to match the duplicate issue.